# How to modify payload response data in Spring application?

Tags: spring-boot, deserialization, resttemplate, objectmapper

I' m trying to add a random payload to the responses of a web service implemented with Spring Boot. My current  approach is registering a ControllerAdvice component which modify the response body in the following manner:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class PayloadInflater implements ResponseBodyAdvice {

    protected Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(PayloadInflater.class.getName());

    @Value("${network.increased-payload:false}")
    private boolean increasedPayload;
    @Value("${network.payload-size:1000000}")
    private int payloadSize;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
        return increasedPayload;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        byte[] randomData = new byte[payloadSize];
        _logger.info("Generating random data programmatically");
        new Random().nextBytes(randomData);

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("payload", body);
        map.put("benchmarkPayload", randomData);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I've a frontend app also implemented in Spring Boot and using a RestTemplate and I'm not able to deserialize correctly the messages from the service.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Boolean out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@36ac8a63; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Boolean out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@36ac8a63; line: 1, column: 1]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:240)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:917)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
        at DeserializationTest.deserializationTest(DeserializationTest.java:52)
        at DeserializationTest.deserializationTest(DeserializationTest.java:42)
        at DeserializationTest.whenReadingBoolean_thenCorrect(DeserializationTest.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Boolean out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@36ac8a63; line: 1, column: 1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseBoolean(StdDeserializer.java:220)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$BooleanDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:178)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$BooleanDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:161)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2922)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:237)
        ... 45 more
```

this is an example of the body data get from the service:

```
{
   "payload": true,
   "benchmarkPayload": "this is a random string"
}
```

Comment: can you clarify when are you getting that exception? can you post a full stacktrace?

Comment: If a valid JSON is being returned from your service and if you are getting exception when deserialize that message on the client app then its an issue with your client app. please post how are you doing api call and handling the responses

Comment: What you show above as a response isn't valid JSON.  The keys and the string value need to have double quotes around them.  That body is always going to lead to errors if you try to parse it as JSON.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it by hand...actually it is a valid json. I'll edit the question

Comment: I make the api call with a RestTemplate "restTemplate.getForObject(URL, Boolean.class);"